# Prove that $2$ is a quadratic residue modulo primes of the form $7.2^n-1$, where $n\geq 3$

Tags: number-theory

> Prove that $2$ is a quadratic residue modulo primes of the form $7.2^n-1$, where $n\geq 3$

I have no attack on this. I know that this works for $n=5$. Could someone give me a hint?

Comment: Congruent to $-1$ modulo $8$, then quote standard result.

Comment: @AndréNicolas- What standard result would that be?

Comment: That $2$ is a QR of the odd prime $p$ if and only if $p\equiv \pm 1\pmod{8}$.